Let $\phi: \mathbb Z_{15} \to \mathbb Z_{15}$ with $\phi(2)=5$. What is $\phi(1)?$
Let $\phi: \mathbb Z_{15} \to \mathbb Z_{15}$ with $\phi(2)=5$. What is $\phi(1)?$
Of course, $\phi(2)= \phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=2\phi(1)=5$. So, $\phi(1)=\dfrac{5}{2}$ but there is not element $\dfrac{5}{2}$ in $\mathbb Z_{15}$.
Where is the point I miss? Since I couldn't find $\phi(1)$, couldn't find $\phi(x)$ either.

Notice that $2$ in $2.\phi(1)$ is not necessarily the $2$ in the group/ring.

Are you saying that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of the additive group of integers mod $15$?  Then you can find $\phi(1)$ from $\phi(1)+\phi(1)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(2)=5\equiv20\bmod15$

It is not true what you say. $\dfrac 52$ IS AN ELEMENT OF $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$ because $2$ is inversible and its inverse is obviously $8$. So $\phi (1)=10$

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before.

This is a very basic question about $\Bbb Z_n.$  It can easily be considered a dupe.

Hint:  you have $2\phi(1)=5 =5+15=20$ in $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$.

This implies that you can divide by $2$.  You can't.  You have to multiply by $8$.

Thus, this answer is misleading.

$2x\equiv20\bmod15\iff15\mid2x-20\iff15\mid x-10\iff x\equiv10\bmod 15$ since $\gcd(2,15)=1$ (generalized Euclid's lemma)

Okay, fair enough.  (+1)

You can find $\phi(x),$ since $1$ is not the only generator of $\Bbb Z_{15}.$   There are $8=\varphi (15)$ of them,  where $\varphi $ is Euler's phi function.
They are $1,2,4,7,8,11,13$ and $14.$
One way to go is to find $\phi(1).$  It may make it easier.
$\phi (1)=\phi(8\cdot 2)=8\phi(2)=8\cdot 5=40\equiv 10,$ in $\Bbb Z_{15}.$
Thus $\phi(x)=\phi(x\cdot 1)=x\cdot \phi (1)=10x\pmod{15}.$

You must be careful on what "$=$" means here. You are working with the integers modulo $15$ under addition, so "$2\phi(1)=5$" actually means $2\phi(1)\equiv 5\pmod{15}\iff$ $2\phi(1)=$ $15k+5=$ $5(3k+1)$, for $k\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore, necessarily $2\mid 3k+1$, and the only solution $0\le\phi(1)\le14$ is gotten for $k=1$, which yields $\phi(1)=10$.

Why would someone downvote this?
